# SNMP.exe on a physical server with Windows Server 2003 consistently takes 20% of CPU utilization

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, snmp, cpu-usage

snmp.exe takes 20% cpu utilization, irrespective of any other processes running/stopped on the server. 
The machine has HP hardware (oops, not IBM)
When we stop the snmp service, the CPU utilization is back to normal. Can anyone help on this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

investigate to see if the vendor has updates for any of the management tools. It's likely that some of the HPSIM or other management agents is or contains an SNMP sub-agent that is behaving badly.

It's also possible that it's the main SNMP service from MS, so see if you have any SNMP-related patches available, but IME it's more likely to be the former issue.

Comment: I believe, the management agent was in conflict with the ServeRaid manager. I set the ServeRAID service to Manual and this is fixed now. Thanks for looking in to this with so little info.

Comment: ServeRAID is IBM, not HP. And I've actually run into this specific issue with IBM ServeRAID, SNMP, and CPU.

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=268287

Answer (score 0):

Are you running any monitoring software on the server? How about Intel Proset? I know with some versions of Dell's Openmanage, you will see high SNMP usage, but not sure about HP.